# I/O in Java with class files

Tags: java, io

I am writing an IO device that writes an classes definition (class file) as well its current state (data/variable values) to an file. Now writing the state is fine but it's definition is what I have a question for.

I know how to use Javacompiler class in the reflection API but what I am not sure about is how the compiler does it's job.

Like suppose I am compiling the source code for class A and this class has references to Class B and so on. My doubt are

1)will the compiler recursively compile class B and it's dependencies?

2)If so should I write all those files as well?

3)Is there a better way to all of this?

I want to make my IO file almost like an mini application where source code and their data co exist. I already have made an system where only data can be written (not serialization) with separate IO classes but I want to take it a step further.